# How do field types convert from json and SF object

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, sobject

I am working on a lwc. I am passing a array of json objects into a apex method. The parameter for the apex method is a List<Work_Items> where work items is a SF object. At run time apex converts the json to a list of work items but how to the sobjects field types convert. I have a flag field and need to check it. Will the json value for the field be converted to a bool on the sobject or will it be a string?

Answer (score 2):

The types are all pretty much what you'd expect from JSON. Boolean values will be true/false (not String values). What follow is, I believe, what each type will be converted to, based on my experience. I haven't tested all of these, though, so a few may be incorrect; please feel free to let me know if any of these are wrong.

| Apex Schema.DisplayType | JavaScript |
| --- | --- |
| address | Object of Fields e.g. { street: String, city: String, ... } |
| any | String |
| base64 | String |
| Boolean | Boolean true or false |
| Combobox | String |
| Currency | Number |
| DataCategoryGroupReference | String |
| Date | String |
| DateTime | String |
| Double | Number |
| Email | String |
| EncryptedString | String |
| ID | String |
| Integer | Number |
| Location | Object of fields { lat: Number, long: Number, ... } |
| Long | Number |
| MultiPicklist | String, semi-colon separated |
| Percent | Number |
| Phone | String |
| Picklist | String |
| Reference | Id or Object of fields e.g. { name: String, ... } |
| String | String |
| TextArea | String |
| Time | String |
| URL | String |

Comment: so true or false will in a json object will convert to a checkbox field as a bool

Comment: @Zdev That is correct.

Comment: Worth noting the ISO formatting of date/time values, being in UTC. Weirdly the JSON and REST APIs handle some of this differently, IIRC.